# How to invoke npm via sbt in a multi-module project

Tags: sbt

I am using sbt to build a multi-module project.  One of the modules is a JavaScript application which builds with npm.  I would like to simply execute npm via a shell script as part of the package task, and use the resulting output file as the artifact for that module. I am able to run a shell command as part of the package task, but for some reason this task is ignored when I run publish or publishLocal.

Attached is my Build.scala.

It is the accounts-ui project which should build using npm.  Right now the actual npm build is represented by a simple script.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
import play.PlayScala
import sbtassembly._
import AssemblyKeys._
import net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
import ohnosequences.sbt.SbtS3Resolver.autoImport._

object Build extends Build {

  lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "myorg",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
  )

  lazy val publishSettings = Seq(
    publishTo := {
      val prefix = if (isSnapshot.value) "snapshots" else "releases"
      Some(s3resolver.value("MyOrg " + prefix + " S3 bucket", s3(prefix+".repo.myorg.com")))
    }
  )

  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
    name := "accounts-root"
  ).settings(publishSettings).aggregate(api, ui)

  val _apiName = "accounts-api"

  lazy val api = Project(id = "api", base = file("./api")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
    name := "accounts-api",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      specs2
    )
  ).settings(publishSettings).settings(graphSettings).settings(
    mainClass in assembly := Some("play.core.server.NettyServer"),
    fullClasspath in assembly += Attributed.blank(PlayKeys.playPackageAssets.value),
    test in assembly := {},
    assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := { 
      val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
      cp filter { (el) => {
          val name = el.data.getName
          name.contains("mockito") || name.contains("commons-logging") || name.contains("specs2")
        }
      }
    }
  ).settings(addArtifact(Artifact(_apiName, "assembly"), assembly)
  ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

  val npmBuildTask = taskKey[Unit]("some custom task")

  lazy val ui = Project(id = "ui", base = file("./ui")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
    name := "accounts-ui",
    npmBuildTask := {
      val processBuilder = Process("npm-build.sh")
      val process = processBuilder.run()
      if(process.exitValue() != 0)
        throw new Error(s"custom task failed with exit value ${process.exitValue()}")
    },
    Keys.`package` <<= (Keys.`package` in Compile) dependsOn npmBuildTask
  ).settings(publishSettings)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it as follows:

```
  val npmPackageTask = taskKey[File]("npm package task")

  lazy val ui = Project(id = "ui", base = file("./ui")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
    name := "accounts-ui",
    npmPackageTask := {
      val processBuilder = Process("npm-build.sh")
      val process = processBuilder.run()
      if(process.exitValue() != 0)
        throw new Error(s"custom task failed with exit value ${process.exitValue()}")
      file(".")
    },
    packageBin in Compile <<= npmPackageTask
  ).settings(publishSettings)
```

The key was to create the key as taskKey[File], use the packageBin key, and replace the task with the <<= operator.